# Regex in Rails Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to create a routes where any value is accepted, I have created one like this

`get '/coworking-in-:coworking_place', to: 'home#coworking', constraints: { :coworking_place => /[a-z]*[A-Z]*/ }`

It is working fine with following cases:

1. www.aboardoffices.com/coworking-in-delhi
2. www.aboardoffices.com/coworking-in-mumbai

But it is not working in the following cases:

1. www.aboardoffices.com/coworking-in-sector7Dwarka
2. www.aboardoffices.com/coworking-in-dlfPhase1Gurgaon

I want to create route that can accept any parameters in :coworking_place

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression `/[a-z]*[A-Z]*/` doesn't capture all the groups. See - http://rubular.com/r/laRElzp1QU

You probably need `/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/`. This whitelists all upper-case, lowercase characters, numbers, and `-`. Check result - http://rubular.com/r/niCKQDQIjl